# Sent SALT tokens to Cindicator (CND) contract address by mistake

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, myetherwallet, tokens

I sent SALT tokens to Cindicator (CND) contract address by mistake. Is it possible to recover the tokens. Below is the transaction hash
0xbfe1b24ddef1ac36b646c7e6bbd87f8fe9401dcd856b74691780b15865c10392

I see the following method in the CND contract source https://etherscan.io/address/0xd4c435f5b09f855c3317c8524cb1f586e42795fa#code

```
/// @notice This method can be used by the controller to extract mistakenly
///  sent tokens to this contract.
/// @param _token The address of the token contract that you want to recover
///  set to 0 in case you want to extract ether.
function claimTokens(address _token) public onlyController {
```

Does this mean the contract owner can return my SALT tokens?. Someone please help here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the target is no user you can contact or a contract having the neccessary function implemented, there is no way you can get your tokens back. I'm sorry, hopefully the loss is not too high.

Comment: When I look at the source code for CND contract it has the following.   function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount
    ) returns (bool success) {

        // The controller of this contract can move tokens around at will,
        //  this is important to recognize! Confirm that you trust the
        //  controller of this contract, which in most situations should be
        //  another open source smart contract or 0x0
      }

Comment: Does this mean the owner of the contract can return the funds?

Comment: this is for when you allow somebody else to transfer your tokens. that person then can use this function to transfer the tokens you allowed him to transfer.